# Is this saying about four things supporting the world an authentic hadith?

Tags: hadith, source-identification

Is the following a quote from authentic hadith by Prophet Mohamed:

> Four things support the world: the learning of the wise, the justice of the great, the prayers of the good, and the valor of the brave.

Answer (score 3):

I was unable to find any Hadith similar to that. But I did stumble across links that attributed the quote to [Elijah Muhammed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elijah_Muhammad) and not Prophet Muhammed (SAW).

Source:
1. [Elijah Muhammad Quotes](http://www.azquotes.com/author/23167-Elijah_Muhammad)